# Django / Ajax: javascript object formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I'm new to javascript and jquery. I have the following situation. I'm serializing an edited row of a table and sending it to the server via ajax.

I have to pass the original data (before editing) and the final data (edited row) to the server.

Passing each of them separately is working well, but when I put them together something strange is happening. It's probably something trivial for those who understand javascript well.

The "sending code" is:

```
$.ajax({
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        ...
       });
```

when I get the original row data or the edited row data as:

```
data = tr.find(':input').serializeArray();
```

I get a normal dict in request.POST, like this:

```
<QueryDict: {u'Type': [u'CNAME'], u'Name': [u'domain_2'], Ttl': [u'500'], u'Value': [u'domain_1']}>
```

But when I try to get both original and new data like this:

```
original_data = tr.find(':input').serializeArray();
new_data = tr.find(':input').serializeArray();
var data = {}
data.original_data = original_data
data.new_value = new_data
```

This just does not work. I get something like this:

```
<QueryDict: {u'new_value[1][name]': [u'Type'], u'new_value[3][name]': [u'Ttl'], u'new_value[2][value]': [u'domain_1'], u'original_data[2][name]': [u'Value'], u'new_value[2][name]': [u'Value'], u'original_data[0][name]': [u'Name'], u'original_data[3][value]': [u'300'], u'original_data[1][value]': [u'CNAME'], u'new_value[3][value]': [u'500'], u'original_data[0][value]': [u'domain_2'], u'new_value[1][value]': [u'CNAME'], u'original_data[3][name]': [u'Ttl'], u'new_value[0][name]': [u'Name'], u'original_data[2][value]': [u'domain_1'], u'original_data[1][name]': [u'Type'], u'new_value[0][value]': [u'domain_2']}>
```

I was hoping to get

```
<QueryDict: {'original_data': {u'Type': [u'CNAME'], u'Name': [u'domain_2'], Ttl': [u'500'], u'Value': [u'domain_1']}, 'new_value': {u'Type': [u'CNAME'], u'Name': [u'domain_2'], Ttl': [u'500'], u'Value': [u'domain_1']}>>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use `encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data))` instead of `data` only.

As I'm using django, I also used dajaxice, so I actually added `'argv='+encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data))`, so Dajaxice looks for a key called `'argv'` and gets the value to me.

Answer (score 0):

`request.POST` is for data sent as normal form-encoded. You're not sending that, you're sending a raw JSON string. To access that in the view, use `request.body`.

Comment: how do I encode data in request.POST correctly. in request.body I have: 'new_data%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=Name&new_data%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=domain_2&new_data%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=Type&new_data%5B1%5D%5Bvalue%5D=CNAME&new_data%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=Value&new_data%5B2%5D%5Bvalue%5D=domain_1&new_data%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=Ttl&new_data%5B3%5D%5Bvalue%5D=500&original_data%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=Name&original_data%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=domain_2&original_data%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=Type&original_data%5B1%5D%5Bvalue%5D=CNAME& ... (I had to truncate the data, becasue of limits of chars)
request.POST is the correct structure to access